# If $A,B \in \mathfrak g$ then $[A,B] \in \mathfrak g.$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Let $E$ be a Banach space. Let $G \subseteq GL(E)$ be a closed subgroup i.e. $G$ is a linear Banach Lie group. Define $$\mathfrak g : = \left \{X \in \mathcal L(E)\ \big |\ \forall t \in \Bbb R, e^{tX} \in G \right \}.$$ If $A,B \in \mathfrak g$ then show that $[A,B] \in \mathfrak g,$ where $[A,B] : = AB - BA.$

Since $A,B \in \mathfrak g$ it follows that $e^{tA},e^{tB} \in G,$ for all $t \in \Bbb R.$ From here how do I prove that $e^{t(AB-BA)} \in G,$ for all $t \in \Bbb R\ $? Can anybody please help me?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** $:$ I think that I get it. I previously proved that

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left (e^{\frac {A} {\sqrt {n}}} e^{\frac {B} {\sqrt {n}}} e^{-\frac {A} {\sqrt {n}}} e^{-\frac {B} {\sqrt {n}}} \right )^n = e^{[A,B]}.$$

Now since $G$ is a closed subgroup, the result follows immediately.